# Symfony 3 (Prod) : You have requested a non-existent service "assetic.asset_manager"

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I'm trying to run this cmd, which is supposed to dump assetic files for prod environment :

```
php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

This cmd returns the following error :

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
>       You have requested a non-existent service "assetic.asset_manager".

When i try to access the prod page through my browser, i've got the following error :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>       ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_2f6a151_0" as such route does not exist.")
>       in YOCoreBundle::layout.html.twig at line 14

Everything is working fine in the dev environment (static files are minified and stored in the right folder) when i run this cmd :

```
php bin/console assetic:dump
```

Regarding my configuration :

In composer.json :

```
{
  "require": {
     "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8.0",
     "leafo/scssphp": "~0.6",
     "patchwork/jsqueeze": "~1.0"
  }
}
```

In app/config/config.yml i have the following code :

```
assetic:
  debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
  use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
  filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    jsqueeze:   ~
    scssphp:
      formatter: 'Leafo\ScssPhp\Formatter\Compressed'
```

AsseticBundle is declared in the AppKernel.php :

```
$bundles = [
  new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
];
```

I don't really know where the problem might be.
If anyone has an idea about that, it would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try to clear the cache with the cache:clear command on the prod env ?

Comment: Thanks for that ! I just did it. I don't have the error coming from the cmd prompt anymore. But the error when visiting the prod page through the browsse is still there.

Answer (score 4):

@Freelancer, the answer you gave was for Symfony2, be the op is using Symfony3.

The commands you need to clear the production cache are:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

and to clear the dev (development) cache are:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

There is no need for the --no-debug. Also, a lot of time in the dev environment, you won't need to clear cache for certain changes (i.e. twig changes); but definitely clear the cache for prod when you make significant changes.

Edit #2.
You might need to run this command as well:

```
$ php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

Try it!

Comment: Thanks. I used both commands, one after another :

`php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`
`php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod`

But this problem still persists when visiting the prod :

`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_2f6a151_0" as such route does not exist.") in YOCoreBundle::layout.html.twig at line 14`

Comment: Thanks. I ran it, emptied the cache, ran it again... the problem persists : i'm still unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_2f6a151_0"

Comment: it's here : `----------------------------------- ---------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
  Name                                Method     Scheme   Host   Path
 ----------------------------------- ---------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
  _assetic_2f6a151_0                  ANY        ANY      ANY    /css/2f6a151_main_1.css`

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a cache problem, as you said everything work fine in dev mode probably because symfony has regenerated the cache in dev but not into your prod env.

I think you should run the following command to solve it:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Comment: Thanks. As @alvin-bunk said, i'm using Symfony 3.1, so now its bin instead of app. Anyway, clearing the cache solved the first error (the one from the cmd line), but not the one displayed in the browser when visiting the prod site.